# Description problem with CS.StackExchange

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, site-description

On the Stack Exchange accounts list there is a problem with description of CS.StackExchange:

It's missing.

Screenshot:

[image: list of sites with the missing description]

Comment: Dang, @Martijn is simply too fast for me.

Comment: Yeah. Didn't search for "Summary"...